# Updating image URLs in HTML paste emails - Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

In the classic editor you used to be able to upload your images and it would keep the image name and append it with your branded url. This made updating the images in your HTML paste email really easy. As they all used the same URL. However, in Content Builder when you upload your images they now don't seem to use your branded domain. Making updating your image URLs tricky. Does anyone have a work around for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'Updating' - do you mean overwriting the existing image with a new version?

Comment: Not really, more updating the image location. For example when you paste in your HTML your image location might be in Images/banner.jpeg
After you upload your images into the Content Builder the image becomes something like: http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe8f13737565037a72/m/1/49924a50-7b74-485f-bd7d-853f5fdab98d.jpg
And doesn't use the branded URL that it does in Portfolio. 
This makes it hard to update all the image locations in the HTML.

Comment: If you have a private domain, as it sounds like you do in portfolio, you should be able to put a helpdesk ticket in to have it also on content builder.